# Need Help setting up a unusual related rates problem (Calc AB)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Currently I am doing a project in my calculus class where we create a related rate problem relating to 2 ideas pulled out of a hat and solve it(mine was a student(s) bored in class and souls). Being a kind of weird combination, the problem I came up with is:

A student is sitting in one of the most boring classes in history. The class is so boring, that causes the students soul to be sucked out of his body. Every minute, the student loses 4 soul pieces per boredom level. Starting at a level of 0 boredom, the student becomes more and more bored at a rate of 5 boredom levels per minute. If the student's soul is made of 1000 soul pieces, what rate is the student loosing his soul when he has 700 soul pieces remaining?

Originally, I thought I could simply solve this problem using a Pythagorean theorem setup where one side would the total souls, one side would be the boredom [the prime being the rate of it increasing], and my hypotenuse being the lost souls [the prime being the rate of it being lost]. When I started doing the work itself, I got stuck because there was no way to find my base value of the boredom side.

My teacher told me that I had to change something in my problem and not use a Pythagorean theorem setup (Because there was no way of proving it was a triangle problem in the first place). Any ideas on what I should change in my problem and what type of problem it would be (shadow, volume, expanding area, etc)? I think I would have to treat this problem just like a velocity problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link boredom and soul pieces together in terms of time, something like Boredom*Soul pieces= constant, or some other relationship.

---

Incidentally, is this the correct solution?

Let B represent the level of boredom, and S the number of soul pieces left, while t represents time in minutes.

It is given that
$\frac{\mathrm{dS} }{\mathrm{d} t}=-4B$  $(1)$, and

$\frac{\mathrm{dB} }{\mathrm{d} t}= 5$     $(2)$.

Integrating the expression of $(2)$, $B=5t+c$. As initially, boredom level is 0, c=0, and $B=5t$. Therefore, substituting this into $(1)$, we find that $\frac{\mathrm{dS} }{\mathrm{d} t}=-20t$.

Integrating, $S=-10t^2+c$, as S=1000 initially, $S=1000-10t^2$. When S=700, $t=\sqrt{3}$. So rate of change of soul pieces= $\frac{\mathrm{dS} }{\mathrm{d} t}=-20 \sqrt{3}$ pieces a minute?

Comment: all your work matches mine. I have to also somehow draw this so I can have a visual representation when I share it to the class. Any idea on how I would go about drawing this?

Comment: @Veir I honestly have no idea how to pictorially represent it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have (boredom)$\times$(soul) $=$ (constant).  Then if boredom is at such and so level and changing at whatever rate, how is soul changing?